# int16 number plus float64 in golang

Tags: go, int, typeconverter

I want to do a simple thing:

```
func (this *ScoreProvider) getScore()(res float64) {
    var score1 int16 = 500
    var score2 int16 = 400
    var score3 int16 = 300
    var score4 int16 = 200
    res = score1 * 0.25 + score2 * 0.25 + score3 * 0.25 + score4 * 0.25

    return
}
```

But this reports an error:

```
can not use score1 * 0 + score2 * 0 + score3 * 0 + score4 * 0 (type int16) as type float64 in assignment
```

How can I do this right?

Comment: What version of go are you using? This gives an error, "constant 0.25 truncated to integer" in go1.4. http://play.golang.org/p/SJmHxgXm9k

Comment: this does report an error, I want to know how to do this quickly?

Answer (score 3):

Go does not provide implicit numeric conversion, see this FAQ: [Why does Go not provide implicit numeric conversion?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#conversions).

This means you can't mix different types when doing arithmetic operations. They have to be of the same type. [Spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators):

> The operand types must be [identical](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_identity) unless the operation involves shifts or untyped [constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants).

Your case is a little different because `0.25` is an [untyped constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) but since it has a fraction part it can't be converted/interpreted as `int16` so you get a compile time error. From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants):

> It is an error if the constant value cannot be represented as a value of the respective type.

You have 3 options in this case:

1. Explicitly convert scores to `float64`:

   ```
   res = float64(score1) * 0.25 + float64(score2) * 0.25 +
       float64(score3) * 0.25 + float64(score4) * 0.25
   ```
2. Use `float64` type for your `score` variables.

   ```
   var score1 float64 = 500
   var score2 float64 = 400
   // ...
   ```
3. Since your algorithm calculates average, you can simply do:

   ```
   res = float64(score1 + score2 + score3 + score4) / 4
   ```

Comment: Number 3 suffers from `int16` overflow/underflow problems.

Comment: @PaulHankin Yes, that has to be kept in mind. Given the example numbers it's not a problem in this case. And if numbers would be big enough so that adding 4 of them would cause an overflow, `int16` would already be a bad choice to represent scores anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Your constants (0.25) are being truncated to intergers (0).

Two ways to solve:

cast the score1 etc variables to float32:

```
var score1 int16 = 500
var score2 int16 = 400
var score3 int16 = 300
var score4 int16 = 200
res := float32(score1)*0.25 + float32(score2)*0.25 + float32(score3)*0.25 + float32(score4)*0.25

fmt.Println("Score", res)
```

or more sensible, instead of declaring them as int16 declare them as float32 to begin with:

```
var score1a float32 = 500
var score2a float32 = 400
var score3a float32 = 300
var score4a float32 = 200
res2 := score1a * 0.25 + score2a * 0.25 + score3a * 0.25 + score4a * 0.25

fmt.Println("Result 1", res)
fmt.Println("Result 2", res2)
```

On the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JL4ygQ8U4z)

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic type promotion in go and you need to include explicit conversions instead.

I'd write your code something like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func getScore() float64 {
    s1, s2, s3, s4 := int16(500), int16(400), int16(300), int16(200)
    return (float64(s1) + float64(s2) + float64(s3) + float64(s4)) * 0.25
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(getScore())
}
```